# Filter list of strings to not contain any of the string from another list as a substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have following code to select the values which are not contained in the another list.

```
import re
isbn  = ["1111","2222","3333","4444","5555"]
sku = ["k1 1111", "k2 2222", "k3 3333", "k4 4444", "k5 5555", "k6 6666", "k7 7777", "k8 8888" ,"k9 1111"]

for x in isbn:
    for i in sku:
        if x not in i:
            print (i)
```

Expected outcome should be like this:

```
k6 6666
k7 7777
k8 8888
```

But I get all unmatched values. How can I get the expected outcome as I showed above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) within your loop. Infact you may achieve it using below *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> list_1  = ["1111","2222","3333","4444","5555"]
>>> list_2 = ["k1 1111", "k2 2222", "k3 3333", "k4 4444", "k5 5555", "k6 6666", "k7 7777", "k8 8888" ,"k9 1111"]

>>> [x for x in list_2 if not any( y in x for y in list_1)]
['k6 6666', 'k7 7777', 'k8 8888']
```

Here `any` will return `True` if any of string in `list_1` is present as substring in `list2`. As soon as it finds the match, it will short-circuit the iteration *(without checking for other matches)* and will return the result as `True`.

In case if you are not interested in using `any`, you may get the same result with the below `for` loop as:

```
for x in list_2:
    for y in list_1:
        if y in x:
            break
    else:
        print(x)
```

which will print your desired output:

```
k6 6666
k7 7777
k8 8888
```

Comment: At the bottom code which is without any(). Why that else is lined with for not lined with if.

Comment: @LandOwner that `else` will be executed if your `for` loop completes the iteration without the execution of `break`. In case if your `if` condition returns `True`, `break` will stop the inner loop and in that case `else` won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to test **all** values in `isbn` before you can conclude none of those match.

Rather than loop over `isbn` first, loop over `sku` and test that value with each of the `isbn` values; the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) makes that easier and more efficient:

```
for value in sku:
    if not any(i in value for i in isbn):
        print(value)
```

More efficient still would be to *split out* the ISBN portion, and test against a set:

```
isbn_set = set(isbn)
for value in sku:
    isbn_part = value.partition(' ')[-1]  # everything after the first space
    if isbn_part not in isbn_set:
        print(value)
```

This avoids looping over `isbn` altogther; set membership testing takes O(1) constant time; for N skus and M ISBN values, this makes a O(N) loop (vs O(NM) loop with `any()`).

Either version can be converted to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to produce a list of matches; the preferred set version then becomes:

```
isbn_set = set(isbn)
not_matched = [value for value in sku if value.partition(' ')[-1] not in isbn_set]
```

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> isbn  = ["1111","2222","3333","4444","5555"]
>>> sku = ["k1 1111", "k2 2222", "k3 3333", "k4 4444", "k5 5555", "k6 6666", "k7 7777", "k8 8888" ,"k9 1111"]
>>> isbn_set = set(isbn)
>>> [value for value in sku if value.partition(' ')[-1] not in isbn_set]
['k6 6666', 'k7 7777', 'k8 8888']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove matches from a set, then the left over set is what you are after:

#### Code:

```
skus = set(sku)
for x in isbn:
    skus -= {i for i in skus if x in i}
```

#### Test Code:

```
isbn = ["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555"]
sku = ["k1 1111", "k2 2222", "k3 3333", "k4 4444", "k5 5555", "k6 6666",
       "k7 7777", "k8 8888", "k9 1111"]

skus = set(sku)
for x in isbn:
    skus -= {i for i in skus if x in i}
print(skus)
```

#### Results:

```
{'k6 6666', 'k7 7777', 'k8 8888'}
```

Comment: That's not the most intuitive path, and still a O(NM) solution.

Comment: Actually, this is worse than O(NM), as you loop over N skus for M isbn values, and the subtraction is another loop over up to N values, so O(N**2M), worse than what the OP had.